# How to make links that redirect you to the same document in google docs?

Tags: google-docs

How to make links that redirect you to the same document in google docs?

I'm quoting some stuff in google docs. How can I make it similar to wiki style?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia

I want to know how to use this feature when quoting:

1. To be redirected to the quote

Edit: It doesn't have to be a link. Notes (1,2,3,4,5...) that will allow me to do the same are just as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, you are trying to create a system of internal links in a Google Doc. There are two effective ways to accomplish this.

One, take advantage of different headings from `Format > Paragraph styles`. You can modify the look and feel of these headings as you see fit. Then, when you highlight text to create a link, you will have the option of linking to the different headings you have created.

Two, create bookmarks within your document using `Insert > Bookmark`. This would be more suited to links that aren't headings but might be the start of a paragraph of something smaller that does not merit a heading. You can then create the link as with the previous option.

The design choice between the two is yours; you can mix and match them as well.

Comment: And about my second question? I'm looking for something like a footnote where I can see the quote by just hovering over it with my mouse (the exact thing that wiki does).

Comment: @TheBeast That I cannot speak to. I suspect you'd need a specific add-on or script to accomplish that.

Comment: I'll edit this question and ask another one asking for that particular function then. Thanks!